# Html.Label to display email address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.label

I am using Html.Label to display some data in my MVC applilcation. When I am trying to display email address it does not render properly

```
Model.CopyToEmail = lab@gmail.com
@Html.Label((string)(Model.CopyToEmail))
```

but the rendered output  that i see is

```
com
```

Could anyone please suggest how to display using Html.Label

```
lab@gmail.com
```

Comment: can you post your view code as well as your controller code that populates your model

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Html.Label` takes a field to display a `<label>` tag for.
It's reading your string as a nested property, and printing the name of the innermost property.

You just want to write ordinary text:

```
@Model.CopyToEmail
```

You can also call `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CopyToEmail)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using strongly typed views (passing viewmodels to views, and *not using ViewBag/ViewData*) is good practice, and allows you to use generic overloads of html helpers. Here is your example rewritten using strongly typed html helper

```
Html.LabelFor(model => model.CopyToEmail)
```

And label in html is not there to display data, it is there *to label* property being edited. You could use [[DisplayAttribute]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) on your property, or use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg453858%28v=vs.98%29)

```
public static MvcHtmlString Label(
    this HtmlHelper html,
    string expression,
    string labelText
)
```

//

```
Html.LabelFor(model => model.CopyToEmail, Model.CopyToEmailLabelText)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please look at the model OR your data source to the view to return the property value:  i.e. like, `Html.Encode(Model.Email)`

Comment: Razor encodes automatically.  And encoding wouldn't do this anyway.