# jQuery Mobile Collapsible is splitting my strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, razor

I have a MVC mobile project with a collapsible list that is populated with data from a db. All of the data passes correctly in the view but my strings that contain a period( . ) is being split.

**For example:**

For **Test Company Inc.** nothing will appear
and for **testemail@gmail.com** only the **com** will appear.

As a temp. fix, I added this code to get rid of the period.

```
foreach (var item in Customers)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(item.Name, @"[.]"))
    {
        item.Name = item.Name.Replace(@".", "");
    }
}
```

Here is my Razor

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>@Html.Label(item.Name)</h3>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Address)
                @Html.Label(item.Address)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => item.City)
                @Html.Label(item.City)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => item.State)
                @Html.Label(item.State)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Contact)
                @Html.Label(item.Contact)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => item.Email)
                @Html.Label(item.Email)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => item.PhoneNo)
                @Html.Label(item.PhoneNo)
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Final HTML

Entry that works.

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed">
    <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
        <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">
            <label for="TestCompany">TestCompany</label>
            <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
        </a>
    </h3>

    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">          
            <div>
                <label class="customerInfoLabel" for="item_Address">Address:</label>
                <label class="customerInfo" for="">230 Test Address</label>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Not showing the title, as you can see it never generated the label tag

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed">
    <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
        <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-a">
            <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
        </a>    
    </h3>
    <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">      
        <div>
            <label class="customerInfoLabel" for="item_Address">Address:</label>
            <label class="customerInfo" for="45_Test">45 Test</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of output

[image]

Comment: What does the final rendered HTML look like?

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547631/html-label-to-display-email-address

Comment: That did it. Thanks for your help. If you want to put the link as the answer I'll mark it.